# JavafX: import/export DWG

Tags: javafx, import, export, dwg

Is anyone aware of a JavaFX library that imports DWG files as `Shape`s and exports `Shape`s as DWG `File`?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32142064/4170073

Comment: Thanks!, I came across this post, but the link is for SWING. I was hoping to find something direct to FX.