# Generate DXF drawing in Java

Tags: java, autocad, cad, dxf, dwg

Is there some sort of a good library with documentation to perform the drawings? Something like DWG or DXF files. I need to generate some drawings on the basis of these data. They will be used mainly lines, and dimensioning drawings. You do not necessarily have to be a DWG or DXF. Important for me to do the drawings. Something like that
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoCAD library in Java to read .dwg files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874109/autocad-library-in-java-to-read-dwg-files)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CAD java jar package, called **Ycad**, right now just support DXF drawing...
Download [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ycad/)

Comment: I've seen it already. But the lack of documentation, I do not know what it is about.