# Can I read the Windows file property 'Created With:' from a DWG file in Java?

Tags: java, io, dwg

[This is the Windows file Property 'Created With'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fdbl.png)

I'm trying to do a different job in Java depending on the file property 'created with'. The point is **whether the file property 'Created with' is Inventor or AutoCAD**. It is not supported in basic Java file I/O properties.

Is there a Java library which can read (=parse it to a Java object) the property of a DWG file, or any solution?

The following image is example for the Windows file property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoCAD library in Java to read .dwg files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874109/autocad-library-in-java-to-read-dwg-files)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no java api... if it is, can you inform me?

Comment: In the linked duplicate question, the top-ranked answers discuss several options and provide external links to libraries.